# Why was Hank tagging trees in the college?

Tags: character, analysis, breaking-bad

In S5E8, Hank talks about the job he had when he was on college and implies how simple, but easy the life was back then to Walt. Why that job is selected as the college job of Hank by the writers? Why not delivering newspapers for example? Is there a symbolism/metaphor here?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/breakingbad/comments/zak8j/hanks_talk_about_tagging_trees/

Answer (score 30):

Hank said:

> Oh, yeah? Back in college, I'd spend my days marking trees in the woods with this-- this **orange** spray can.
>
> ......
>
> Crews would come in later and find the trees I tagged and cut them down.
>
> First, you go in, and you mark locations for skid trails and landings.
> Then you choose specific trees all within a selected grid.
> (Script source: [springfieldspringfield](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=breaking-bad&episode=s05e08))

Now if you read it attentively you will notice he said **orange** spray and what other orange prominent thing was in that episode? "Prison uniform", Hank and DEA has marked those people orange too who get killed. Same fate as the tree. So this tree tagging story is just a parallel to what happen to the prisoners.

Same was concluded by [ew.com](https://ew.com/recap/breaking-bad-season-5-episode-5/) too.

Comment: Wow this show is even more brilliant than I realized.

Comment: Everywhere gives the same explanation but the thing is, Hank didn't tag anything. Walt got the names from Lydia.

Comment: @Utku https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreshadowing

Comment: @Utku those people were killed because Walt was afraid of them negotiating a deal (that would lead to him) to avoid prison. Also, being in prison made their location known. Had they been free, there would have been less incentive in killing them and they could have hid or run away. Hank discovery of Gus'operation, the arrest of these men and the failure of the security measures did lead to their deaths.